# How can i count number of particles in each grid box in this code?

Tags: matlab

how can i count number of particles in each grid box in this code

**here is my code below:**

```
xyRange=[1,5];
P=3;
vx=0.6;  
vy=0.4;
X=[];
Y=[];
for day=1:5
    X=[X;randi(xyRange,P,1)];
    Y=[Y;randi(xyRange,P,1)];
    X=X+vx;
    Y=Y+vy;
end 
plot(X,Y,'kd');                
grid on;
axis([1,50,1,50]);
j = floor(X/5)+1; 
k = floor(Y/5);
box = k*10+j;
```

Comment: Wow. I'm probably the only user on Stackoverflow with their own tag. Well, me and the two dozen other beakers. Please remove the **`[beaker]`** tag (this question has nothing to do with Python), format your code so it is somewhat legible, and add some description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Look at the [`hist3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html) function.  It takes in a 2D grid of coordinates and bins similar coordinates together.

Comment: @beaker no-one compels you to answer the question my bad i tagged you if u don't want to answer the question why r u here

Comment: Sorry to interrupt but I think @beaker **wanted** to help you and kindly asked you to format your question properly so that it would be easier to do so. Please don't be offended when people ask you to clarify things, that means they want to help not the opposite. Thanks!

Comment: @Snehaagrawal - It's the least I could do.  One thing I can't stand is poorly formatted posts (no offence).

Comment: @rayryeng i tried to format it but couldn't do it,, as in i don't know why again nd again it was showing error that not properly formatted, i still don't know the proper procedure i recently joined stackoverflow. thanks

Comment: That's fine.  I'll write an answer.

Comment: Sneha agrawal, I was merely amused. Tags are intended to identify the type of question, programming language, things like that; not to identify individual users. As @Benoit_11 said, when people ask for clarification it is so they can more effectively answer without proposing incorrect or useless solutions.  Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, the easiest way is to use [`hist3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html).

In your case, when I plotted the grid, it looks like each box was separated in units of 5.  As such, the command is very simply this:

```
cnt = hist3([X,Y], {0:5:50 - 2.5, 0:5:50 - 2.5});
```

`X` and `Y` are your 2D data points, and the second element is a cell array of `X` and `Y` values which denote the centres of each of the points in each grid.  Take note that the points that are defined are with respect to the origin being at the top left corner.  If you want to make sure that the origin is at the **bottom left** corner, you would actually need to do this:

```
cnt = flipud(cnt.');
```

On my run I get this:

```
cnt =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     5     3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

When producing your plot, I get this:

[image]

If you compare the counts in comparison to the grid produced at the top, you'll see that the match.  However, because of the way I specified the centre of the bins, the first and last row, and the first and last column are meaningless, so you can safely eliminate these from your analysis.

If you want a nice pictorial example of this, call `hist3` without any output arguments:

```
%// Plot 2D histogram with some transparency
hist3([X,Y], {(0:5:50) - 2.5, (0:5:50) - 2.5}, 'FaceAlpha', 0.65);
%// Set height of each bar coloured according to height
set(get(gca,'child'),'FaceColor','interp','CDataMode','auto');
view(-34,68); %// Change camera view for better look
```

We get this:

[image]

Comment: i don't have statistics tool box

Comment: @Snehaagrawal - Too bad!

Comment: @Snehaagrawal - You can always calculate a single 1D index per 2D grid location and compute a histogram of that result, but I'll leave that for you to figure out.  Your post already lacks any effort and I've done more than enough to get things started.

Comment: yeah thanks i am trying to get statistics toolbox trying to download it from matlab central and thanks for your answer it would really help me if have that toolbox. and i'll look upon that histogram thing